# Parse an HTML string to get contents of elements with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, parsing, jeditable

I have the following string that contains several  elements:

```
'<span class="fn" id="fn1">Matthew</span>
<span class="spouse" id="spouse1">Evelyn Ross</span>
<span class="bday" id="bday1">1456</span>
<span class="wday" id="wday1"></span>
<span class="dday" id="dday1">2000</span>'
```

What would be the best way to parse this out to 5 variables?

**EDIT**

For clarity, here's the full code, I'm creating a custom input type for jEditable that allows me to inline edit a vcard.

```
   $.editable.addInputType('person', {
    element : function(settings, original) {     
   var fn  = $('<input id="fn_"/>');
  var bday  = $('<input id="bday_" />');
  var wday  = $('<input id="wday_" />');
  var dday  = $('<input id="dday_" />');
  var spouse  = $('<input id="spouse_" />');

  $(this).append(fn);
  $(this).append(bday);
  $(this).append(wday);
  $(this).append(dday);
  $(this).append(spouse);

        /* Hidden input to store value which is submitted to server. */
        var hidden = $('<input type="hidden">');
        $(this).append(hidden);
        return(hidden);
    },

 content : function(string, settings, original) {
   var $data = $(string);

   var data = {};
   $data.each(function () {
       var $t = $(this);
       data[$t.attr('id')] = {
                              class: $t.attr('class'),
                              value: $t.text()};
   });

   alert(data.length());

   $("#fn_", this).val('Name');
   $("#bday_", this).val('Born');
   $("#wday_", this).val('Married');
   $("#dday_", this).val('Died');
   $("#spouse_", this).val('Spouse');
     },

  submit: function (settings, original) {
  var value =  "<span class=fn>" + $("#fn_").val() + '</span>' + '<span class=spouse>' + $("#spouse_").val() + '</span>' + '<span class=bday>' + $("#bday_").val() + '</span>' + '<span class=wday>' + $("#wday_").val() + '</span>' +'<span class=dday>' + $("#dday_").val() + '</span>';
      $("input", this).val(value);
  }

});
```

Comment: why do you want to store in five variables??? you have .html of jquery which gets..the complete html

Comment: Well I just need to get 5 separate values out by ID. Sorry, if you haven't guessed by now I'm new to this stuff!

Answer (score 6):

Create an element, put it into that element with `innerHTML` and select them out with `querySelector`.

So assuming you wanted to use just plain old js:

```
el = document.createElement('p');
el.innerHTML = '<span class="fn" id="fn1">Matthew</span> ... <span class="dday" id="dday1">2000</span>'
el.querySelector('.fn').innerText // = 'Matthew'
el.querySelector('#fn1').outerHTML // = "<span class="fn" id="fn1">Matthew</span>"
```

Which translates almost directly into jQuery:

```
el = $('<p />').html('<span class="fn" id="fn1">Matthew</span> ... <span class="dday" id="dday1">2000</span>');
el.find('.fn').text() // = 'Mathew'
```

Comment: Assuming that's javascript in a browser.

Comment: Ah didn't notice the jquery tag.

Answer (score 2):

First find the elements then grab data from each element using a combination of [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

You can find the elements by using the usual [selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) string or the raw string you mentioned in the question.

```
var target_string = # ... raw string or selector for '#interesting span'

var $data = $(target_string);

# adjust this to produce the format you want
var data = {};
$data.each(function () {
    var $t = $(this);
    data[$t.attr('id')] = {id: $t.attr('id'),
                           class: $t.attr('class'),
                           value: $t.text()};  # or .html()
});

# you can access this example data via the id values in the html
data['spouse'] # or
data.spouse
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried implementing this (see my edited post above) but it seems to be returning blank. As I understand it, I'm creating an array called data, then searching through the string for elements and inputting them into the array?

Comment: In my example, `data` is a object/dictionary not an array.  `data.length` will return undefined.  `values(data)` will return an array of the values.  You can also check on the `keys(data)`.  This is the part where you need to tweak the formating of `data` to fit into your specific problem space ;^)

Comment: thanks, but when I try values(data), data.values() it still comes up as undefined. I must be missing something...

Comment: If you do not already have it installed, go out and install Firebug for Firefox.  The console in other browsers will also work but Firebug just seems to work best for me.  Then copy and paste my example code into the console.  Update the `target_string` and run it.  Also, since you are just starting out with javascript, try to read up a on the language a little bit.  Douglas Crockford can help here, http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html

Comment: Thanks, I use the inspector in Chrome. I'll brush up on my JS!

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, check out [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
// get text from all spans
var all_text = $('span').text();
// break out into an array of values
var values = all_text.split(' ');
```

**NOTE** this will get the *text* for all `span` tags on the page. So you will want to make a better selector and probably assign this to variables in a better way than `split()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's [`.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).